# How to manually lock a PNR for testing purposes

Tags: sabre

Is there a way to manually lock a PNR in Sabre in order to test error functionality?

We currently have retry logic in our code but creating a testing situation of what to do when a PNR is locked for longer than 3 retries seems to be an issue.  Any guidance you could provide for this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 'lock' a GDS PNR as far as I know, are you referring to what happens when simultaneous changes are detected? There are ways to put a PNR into that state by using multiple sessions but your question is a little unclear.